# What happens if water is treated to AC power supply of 12 kV and 14 kHz?

Tags: electrolysis

Generally water splits to oxygen and hydrogen at $\pu{1.23 V}$. What happens if we treat water at several $\pu{kV}$ with frequency range of $\pu{10 kHz}$ to $\pu{15 kHz}$ AC supply.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Short circuiting, fuse blowing or even buying a new power supply is going to happen.

Comment: Well, you can try it and find out, if you wanna risk your life, that is. BTW 1.23 V isn't enough to make the reaction go with and significant pace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using up to 30 kilovolts is *not* uncommon with aqueous systems in a technique called capillary electrophoresis. Similarly, applying kilohertz current is also common in a technique called conductometry to measure the resistance of aqueous solutions.
In general, when you pass high frequency current, electrolysis does not occur.

You have to check the dielectric breakdown voltage of water, *perhaps with high voltage and high frequency current*, severe Joule heating would be observed, if there is no dielectric breakdown (which means internal sparking).